# Xamarin.Forms: How to get property notification on reference binding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

Consider the following pseudo code.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    IEnumerable<string> _AvailableNames
    public IEnumerable<string> AvailableNames
    {
        get => _AvailableNames;
        set => SetProperty(ref _AvailableNames, value); //Notifies
    }
}
```

View:
`ContentPage`'s ViewModel is a `ViewModel` instance set by dependency injection.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="page" prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True">
    <Element BindingContext="{Binding SelectedElement}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BindingContext.AvailabeNames, Source={Reference page}}" />
    </Element>
</ContentPage>
```

The `AvailableNames` property gets updated on demand, but doesn't get reflected in the UI. I suspect it's because the bound property is `BindingContext.AvailableNames`, is that so? I mean it binds to the `AvailableNames` property, but doesn't get updated when the property changes.

Note, I tried making `AvailableNames` a get-only `ObservableCollection` but adding values to it doesn't reflect to the page either.

I understand that this is because the `ItemsSource` property is bound to the `BindingContext` property of the `usersPage`, is there a way to overcome this (preferably a clean one...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my scenario, it was enough to set back the `BindingContext` to the upper property (i.e. the ViewModel), this will be a limitation in some other scenarios, for instance if I'm binding from within a `ListView` etc.

So the solution is to set it as follows:

```
<ListView
  BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext, Source={Reference usersPage}}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailabeNames}"/>
```

In some scenarios, another option would be a better solution, wrap it with a dummy control like so:

```
<ContentView BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext, Source={Reference usersPage}}">
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems}"/>
</ContentView>
```

I don't know why, but for some controls expecting some value other than `string` (i.e. `Switch`) I can't seem to bind this even with the converter as the value doesn't update. The solution to that is use a dummy control getting the string representation of the value.
In my case I'm using the [`MultiBinding`](https://gist.github.com/Keboo/0d6e42028ea9e4256715#file-multibinding-cs) class, that even its converter always returns `bool` (otherwise will internally throw a `NullReferenceException` and will display nothing), still doesn't update itself properly. With a 3rd party property it works well:

```
<Label x:Name="dummyLabel" Text="{MultiBinding}"/>
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding Text, Source={Reference dummyLabel}}"/>
```

Obviously I'm not a fan of this hacky and ugly code, but that's the only way I found that works.